# How do I perform a VLOOKUP in pandas using merge where NaN is returned if values from left dataframe not found in right dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So the first (and left) dataframe is:

```
Name
Brees
Brady
Rodgers
Mahomes
```

The second (and right) dataframe is:

```
Name
Brees
Brady
Wilson
Mahomes
```

I want to return

```
Name
Brees
Brady
NaN
Mahomes
```

I used the code `pd.merge(df,df1,on="Name",how='left')`, but it returns:

```
Name
Brees
Brady
Rodgers
Mahomes
```

Essentially, the left dataframe is returned

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) with a Boolean series calculated via [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1['Name'] = df1.where(df1['Name'].isin(df2['Name']))

print(df1)
#       Name
# 0    Brees
# 1    Brady
# 2      NaN
# 3  Mahomes
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `merge` can be work after add `indicator`

```
df1.mask(df1.merge(df2,how='left',indicator =True)['_merge']=='left_only')
Out[8]: 
      Name
0    Brees
1    Brady
2      NaN
3  Mahomes
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of the left dataframe and "cross out" the rows whose values are not in the right daraframe:

```
df1 = df.copy()
df1.loc[~df.isin(df2)["Name"], "Name"] = np.nan
#      Name
#0    Brees
#1    Brady
#2      NaN
#3  Mahomes
```